# ListView in Fragment Error Kotlin

Tags: xml, listview, kotlin

New to KT. Im having some errors implementing my list view. Not exactly sure why im having these issues. Is it because it extends a fragment? Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter

class Chatroom : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var listView ListView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        var listView = findViewById(R.id.chatroom_list_view) as ListView

        val testList = "hu, tu, su, send, pe, t"

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testList)
        listView.adapter = adapter


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatroom, container, false)
    }
```

Errors

[Picture of Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJXQB.png)

.xml

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/chatroom_list_view"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="436dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/messageTextField"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like that.

```
class Chatroom : Fragment() {

private lateinit var listView: ListView

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatroom, container, false)

    listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.chatroom_list_view)

    val testList = arrayOf("hu", "tu", "su", "send", "pe", "t")

    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testList)
    listView.adapter = adapter


    return rootView
}
```

Comment: still getting error on ArrayAdapter - cant be called with arguments supplied.

Comment: Try again i changed testList

Comment: Because you wrote "this" instead "context".I open new project and test it for you.It will be work now.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to take note of

```
private lateinit var listView ListView
```

This throws an error because you haven't stated the Type of the object "listView".

In kotlin, object types are stated after a colon proceeding the object name, ie.

```
private lateinit var listView: ListView
```

Next,

```
listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.chatroom_list_view) as ListView
```

Kotlin uses the kotlin extensions (kotlinx) which searches your view hierarchy in context for the ID that belongs to the type of the object it is being assigned. ie. It is sufficient to just say

```
listView = rootView.chatroom_list_view
```

Where rootView is

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.Layout.chatroom, container, false)
```

Which must be declared **before** you use any children from that view.

The next thing is

```
val testList = "hu, tu, su, send, pe, t"
```

is implicitly of type, String

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter), ArrayAdapter (declared in the fashion you want) takes several types as the third parameter, of which string is not mentioned.

Refer to the [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference) manual to see how array of strings are declared.

The final thing to note

```
ArrayAdapter(this,..,..)
```

In this scope, ***this*** is your fragment. Which isn't a context. Use:

```
context
```

Which calls the getter property method of the fragment ***getContext()***. Or :

```
activity
```

Which returns your activity context.

Comment: This is good explanation Chad.I did not know kotlinx work with fragment.Thanks for that.